# How to get trending video list from dailymotion developer api

Tags: dailymotion-api

How to get trending video list from daily-motion developer api.

We can get list of videos using https://api.dailymotion.com/channel/music/videos
but we want videos which are trending.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `sort=trending` filter for trending videos ;) 
https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-sort-filter